# Why ::where('column_name', '=', 'value') is not working in Eloquent/Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

The method in the controller is this:

```php
public function index()
{
    $fields = Field::where('ct_delete', '=', 0);

    return view('system.fields.index', compact('fields'));
}
```

If I change the `where` function for `$fields = Field::all()` the code execute and shows me all of the results as usual. But with the `where` it's returning nothing. I tried with another field and I have no results either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `get()` on the query:

```php
$fields = Field::where('ct_delete', '=', 0)->get();
```

Comment: Seriously? 
I spend almost one hour in it. 
Coding is so ungratefull.
Thank you.